# Contact form returning blank email

Tags: php, zurb-foundation-5

My Foundation 5 contact form is returning blank emails for some reason. The javascript is correct but I can't see anything wrong with my PHP file. What am I doing wrong? Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["t_name"];
$email = $_POST["t_email"];
$message = $_POST["t_message"];

$msg = "
Name: $name
Email: $email
Commments:
$message
";
$to = "me@me.com";
$subject = "From My Site";
$message = $msg;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

the HTML:

```
<div id="contactForm" class="large-6 large-offset-6 columns">
                            <form id="t-contact-form" method="post" data-abide="ajax">
                                <small class="error">Your full name is required.</small>
                                <input name="t_name" id="t_name"  type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                                <small class="error">An email address is required.</small>
                                <input name="t_email" id="d_email" type="email" placeholder="username@address.com" required>
                                <small class="error">Your message is required.</small>
                                <textarea name="t_message" id="d_message" placeholder="Enter your message here" required></textarea>
                                <button class="contact-submit submit">Submit</button>
                                </a>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

and the js:

```
$('#t-contact-form').on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {
        var t_name = $("input#t_name").val();
        var t_email = $("input#t_email").val();
        var t_message = $("textarea#t_message").val();
        // Data for response
        var dataString = 'name=' + t_name + 
            '&email=' + t_email + 
            '&message=' + t_message;
        //Begin Ajax Call
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "assets/php/t-mail.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('#t-contact-form').html("<div id='success'></div>");
                    $('#success').html("<h2>Thanks!</h2>")
                            .append("<p>Dear" + t_name + "!, I look forward to working with you.</p>")
                            .hide()
                            .fadeIn(1500);
                            },
        }); //ajax call
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Where is $headers defined? Also, can you provide the JS, just in case it's not correct?

Comment: Well, in the JS you get the inputs with ID t_message and t_email, but the id's in the HTML are d_email and d_message.

Comment: thanks, that was just a copy/paste error in my post. should have reread it before posting.

Comment: Don't have $headers defined. Didn't think i needed it and also for the sake of keeping it simple to pinpoint the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX call sending using `name` and not `t_name`, same for `email` and `message`. How it was originally named in the HTML doesn't matter to PHP, only the posted data matters.

```
var dataString = 'name=' + t_name + 
        '&email=' + t_email + 
        '&message=' + t_message;
```

So in PHP you should do

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
```

---

Additionally you're getting the inputs by id, but using the names in the JavaScript. Either rename them to `t_email` and `t_message` in the HTML or modify the JavaScript.

```
<input name="t_email" id="t_email" type="email" placeholder="username@address.com" required>
<textarea name="t_message" id="t_message" placeholder="Enter your message here" required></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I added the "name=" in input tags just to cover myself. Perhaps it was an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

In js 
In the third line change #t_email to #d_email and it will work

Comment: The id doesn't matter. It's about the posted data in the AJAX call.

Comment: He is posting the data of #t_email and in the html it is #d_email , that is why he is getting blank email

Comment: I stand corrected, that is also a bug. Though please checkout my answer as well.